# Tuleap - SVN checkout issue : error 500

Tags: tuleap

I'm using the docker image of tuleap in version 8.3.

I setup an AD in `/etc/tuleap/plugins/ldap/etc/ldap.inc` and enable it in `/etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc` with
`$sys_auth_type = 'ldap';`

I then created a subversion project and add my user with the *Add user* button in using the autocompletion ==> my user get recognized, it was never added to tuleap before, so I think the connection with the AD is working.

But when I do a 
`svn list --username myuser http://tuleap/svnroot/toto`, I get :

`Redirecting to URL 'https://tuleap/svnroot/toto':
Authentication realm: <https://tuleap:443> LDAP Subversion Authorization (toto)
Password for 'myuser':
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://tuleap/svnroot/toto'
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request for 'https://tuleap/svnroot/toto'`

I can't find any error in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have appropriate access to checkout the code from repo. If you have access and getting error 500 then please navigate to %appdata%\subversion\auth\svn.simple in Windows

In linux run this command -

rm -f~/.subersion/auth/svn.simple/*

Let us know if this helps you .